# Integration of Google calendar with Salesforce

Tags: integration, calendar

Can anyone please help to integrate Google calendar with Saleforce. Our requirement is user can see calendar in salesforce same as google calendar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Lightning Sync for Google](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/06/introducing-lightning-gmail-sync-for-google.html). In Spring’ 17 Salesforce released this feature which will integrate Google products like Gmail and Calendar with Salesforce.

Here is a [blog post](https://blog.texei.com/lightning-sync-gmail-aa6074458342) explaining step by step process to do the integration.

Please note as per my knowledge, you need a Corporate G Suite account to try this out in Sandbox.

Comment: Using LEX Sync for google will not show me calendar in SFDC? It will add Activities under contact as per my knowledge. I want to show same look and feel of Google Calendar in SFDC.

Comment: I don't think you can change the look and feel of the Salesforce calendar. But you can set up both way sync so that Google calendar events will appear in Salesforce calendar. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sales_lightning_s_g_events_both_ways.htm

Comment: So is there any another way to implement it? To show same look and feel like google chrome.

Comment: I am not aware of any OOB feature. Either you have to search for any AppExchange product or building your own custom solution.